# Dataframe reindexing in order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
   datasource   datavalue
0  aaaa.pdf     5
0  bbbbb.pdf    5
0  cccc.pdf     9
```

I don't know if this is the reason but this seems to be messing a dash display so
I would like to reindex it like

```
   datasource   datavalue
0  aaaa.pdf     5
1  bbbbb.pdf    5
2  cccc.pdf     9
```

I used

```
data_all.reset_index()
```

but it is not working, the index are still 0

how it should be done?

EDIT1:
Thanks to the two participants who made me notice my mistake.
I should have put

```
data_all=data_all.reset_index()
```

Unfortunately it did not go as expected.

Before:

```
   datasource   datavalue
0  aaaa.pdf     5
0  bbbbb.pdf    5
0  cccc.pdf     9
```

Then

```
data_all.keys()
Index(['datasource','datavalue'],dtype='object')
```

So
data_all.reset_index()

After

```
  index   datasource   datavalue
0   0  aaaa.pdf     5
1   0  bbbbb.pdf    5
2   0  cccc.pdf     9
```

data_all.keys()
Index(['index','datasource','datavalue'],dtype='object')

As you see one column "index" was added. I suppose I can drop that column but I was expecting something that in one step reindex the df without adding anything

EDIT2: Turns out `drop=True` was necessary!
Thanks everybody!

Comment: data_all = data_all.reset_index()

Comment: @AhmedAredah Yes thanks. I realized that. However after tryng it it didnt go as expected :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
#drop: Do not try to insert index into dataframe columns. This resets the index to the default integer index.
# inplace: Whether to modify the DataFrame rather than creating a new one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data_all = data_all.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: The OP said it is not working.

Comment: There is a difference between `data_all = data_all.reset_index()` and `data_all.reset_index()`

Comment: @ScottC Yes, I didn't realize that. However it didn't go as well as expected. See EDIT1

Comment: After seeing your edit - yes - it seems that `drop=True` is necessary.